# Java equivalent for Python's 'x in (a, b, c)'?

Tags: java

In Python, I can check if a value exists in a container with `1 in (2, 3)` which returns False. How do I do this in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(2, 3).contains(1)
```

Comment: Aww, and I was going to say "x==1 || x==2 || x==3".

Comment: `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;` to slightly shorten usage.

Comment: @Tom, true, but personally, I'm not a fan of those static imports.

Comment: Yeah, I usually don't. Can be useful to simplify in some situations, particularly if doing it a lot, or trying to compete with Python. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `contains` method of the relevant collection class.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is a Collection, then simply 
 `Collection someCollection ...
  someCollection.contains(someOBject)`

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers live in a `Collection` such as `ArrayList`, or `HashSet` you could use `ourNumbers.contains(1)`.

If your numbers live in a Java array, you could do `Arrays.asList(yourNumbers).contains(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a PS. I saw a really bad way to do this with strings. A programmer writing a dispatching function wanted to test if the module requested was one of certain special modules. So he wrote:

```
if ("login---xlogin---logout---changeuser".indexOf(module)>=0)
...
```

I cringed when I saw it. Sure, if module is login or logout, etc, it will return true. But it will also return true if module is "ogi" or "n---x". If someone unaware of this block of code naively created a new module and named it "xl" or "out" or "change", he would get mysterious errors.